# fault tolerant file systems

Tags: linux, filesystems, fault-tolerance

some filesystems like btrfs and lustre are marked as fault tolerant file systems in :
wiki:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems

what's meaning of fault tolerant file system at all? does it offer some thing more than journaling?

if you enable block journaling in ext3 you can call it fault tolerant or these file systems offer some thing more? my field of interest is to know what these file systems offer about power failure problems?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's meaning of fault tolerant file system at all?

Fault tolerant file system is a replacement of hardware RAID.

> does it offer some thing more than journaling?

Protection against data loss and loss of access to data due to disk drive failure

> if you enable block journaling in ext3 you can call it fault tolerant or these file systems offer some thing more?

No. Need to use Linux software RAID or hardware RAID.

> my field of interest is to know what these file systems offer about power failure problems?

If disk drive failure due to power failure, failure-tolerant disk systems protection data loss.

Comment: and any idea about architecture? how do fault tolerance act as hardware raid? while you lose your disk what do btrfs offer you?